# The name 'serializer' does not exist in the current context Master Page Error in For Java Script C# Web App

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, master-pages

i have use java script successfully running in my project but when i have to use master page and content page for this purpose i create master page and copy all css and script in the head tag of the master page and rest of the controls in the body tag 
  then  i did copy all css and script in the asp:content1 tag while all other thing in the another asp:content2 tag abviously removed all form tags 
   when i compile content page it gave error

"'serializer' does not exist in the current context " in the source file master

actually i use this code in which is actually giving error,

i use this namespace "using System.Web.Script.Serialization;"
then use this code in the code behind file,

```
protected double[] Pvar;
protected JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new 
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
Pvar[runs] = Convert.ToDouble(output.Tables[0].Rows[runs][2]);
```

then for accessing this this array in client side javascript i use this code,

```
 var Arr=<%= serializer.Serialize(Pvar)%>;
```

it giving error in this line but remember code is correct because it is working on a simple ASPX page on the same time side by using master page and content page ..

Hopes for your suggestions,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From which page, are you accessing the `serializer` object? You cannot access protected variable from content code-behind in master page markup and vice versa. So make sure that's not being the case otherwise you need to create public properties/methods and access them by casting Master property in content page (or Page property in Master page) to correct code behind class.

Comment: Since the serialized output is JSON, shouldn't the quotes be left out?

Comment: if it is JSON, should not it be passed onto eval()?

Comment: @Joe, yes - quotes shouldn't be there! I was thinking of having JSON string and then de-serializing using some de-serializer. Buts it's really not needed here.

Comment: @All thanks for your suggestions but i simply all script and css from master page head tags and the error disappear.. . :)